# Test to prove a random selection

Tags: statistical-significance, randomness

An urn has infinite balls of four color, say A, B, C, D. All balls are in equal numbers and they are properly mixed together. A man picks $N$ balls randomly. He picks $w$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ balls of colors A, B, C and D respectively, such that $w+x+y+z=N$. How to test if

1. color A was over represented in the selection?
2. color B was over represented in the selection?
3. color C was over represented in the selection?
4. color D was over represented in the selection?

NB: I found this answer but could not gather much from here. [Proper way to test hypothesis of random selection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193301/proper-way-to-test-hypothesis-of-random-selection)

Comment: Please consult a textbook about the chi-squared test or [search our site for related questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi-squared+test).  That will give you a head start by helping you decide whether there is evidence of non-uniform results.  Then, if you do decide that, the harder part of your question is deciding which (if any!) of the colors were over-represented.  For that, you are likely to find relevant advice by searching for [Tukey HSD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tukey+hsd).

Comment: Can you more clearly identify your aim? Are you after a single test to pick up any deviations from equal probability (the usual approach being a [chi-squared test of goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Discrete_uniform_distribution)), or a test for each individual category (individual tests of proportion)? Or perhaps the first followed by *post hoc* identification of the most discrepant categories? Note that you cannot prove that the categories are selected with equal probability; to come close you may want something like an equivalence test perhaps.

Comment: You may get some value from [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/how-can-i-test-the-fairness-of-a-d20)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll read up on your suggestions, and if I can't figure it out, ask question when I am better informed.